# Elm reactor stuck with error message

Tags: debugging, elm, reactor

I tried to install the seanhess/elm-style package, but could not because it isn't compatible with my version of Elm, 0.18.0. This is fine, but now when I visit any .elm file (even if it's empty), reactor in the browser returns this error:

"Could not find package seanhess/elm-style.

Maybe your elm-stuff/ directory has been corrupted? You can usually fix stuff
like this by deleting elm-stuff/ and rebuilding your project."

I tried restarting reactor, and using new .elm files, even trying to create different errors. No dice.

Any pointers appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Edit: I also removed the import for the seanhess package as a first measure.

Edit: Man, I even restarted the computer, no dice.

Solution: Whewww. So I found elm-package.json and removed the seanhess package from the dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried removing the elm-stuff directory? That usually works in cases like this

Comment: I found the solution, but up until that point, I even uninstalled and reinstalled elm using brew.

Which now that I think of it, may only have reinstalled the compiler.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer to your own question?

Comment: also any links to that package you're installing would be nice

Comment: I don't think the specific package wasn't creating the problem, but here it is: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/seanhess/elm-style/latest